# Android: mediaplayer inside JsonObjectRequest

Tags: java, android, android-volley, media-player

I need to use Mediaplayer inside a JsonObjectRequest. My Code is like this

```
    obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            // The third parameter Listener overrides the method onResponse() and passes
            //JSONObject as a parameter
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ok);
                        mediaPlayer.start();

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("result");


                    }
                    // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                        Log.e("Errore: ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
   }
                }
            },
            // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
            //as a parameter
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.error);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    throw new NullPointerException("uuuuuu");
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> customHeaders = new HashMap<>();

            String login_url = Helper.getConfigValue(getApplicationContext(), "login_url");
            String pwd_url = Helper.getConfigValue(getApplicationContext(), "pwd_url");
            String credentials = login_url + ":" + pwd_url;

            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            customHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            customHeaders.put("Authorization", auth);


            return customHeaders;
        }
    };
```

shareedit delete flag

but i get the error

> "Cannot resolve method 'create(anonymous
>   com.android.volley.Response.Listener, int)"

in MediaPlayer line

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could provide me more code

Answer (score 0):

As your "this" is referring to you volley object

```
MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ok);
```

replace it with you activity reference, like

```
 MediaPlayer.create(yourActivity.this,R.raw.ok);
```

Comment: It return the error 'android.app.Activity' is not an enclosing class

Comment: What's the error now? And add your complete activity code in question not in answer section.

Comment: The error now is in activity.this. It return the error "android.app.Activity' is not an enclosing class"

Comment: By activity i meant the activity in which your are writing this code. If you still can't understand then add complete activity or fragment code from class declaration.